# Получение данных пользователей во vue.js. Json api

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, vue.js, api

Составил на сервере (laravel) json запрос, который получает комментарии статьи

/api/articles/articleUrl/comments

```
 {
           "data": [
              {
                 "type": "comments",
                 "id": "1",
                 "attributes": {
                    "content": "content"
                 },
                 "relationships": {
                    "user": [
                       {
                          "type": "user",
                          "id": "3",
                          "attributes":{
                            "username":"Aisha Quitzon"
                          }
                       }
                    ]
                 }
              },
             ....
           ]
        }
```

Я получил все комментарии через fetch:

Vue:

```
 async fetchComments(){
                this.comments = await fetch('/api/articles/' + articleUrl + '/comments').then(res => {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(comments => comments.data)
            }
```

Перебираю через v-for

```
<div v-for="(comment, index) in comments" :key="index">
        <div>{{ comment.attributes.content }}</div>
        <a id="username">{{ comment.relationships.user[0].attributes.username }}</a> 
        </div>
```

Мне не нравится, то чтобы получить данные от пользователя, приходится длинный код писать `comment.relationships.user[0].attributes.username`

Нужно ли к примеру в колонки user "attributes":{..} ? 
 
Или лучше user - перенести на отдельный api запрос?

Подскажите, как можно это все упростить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему `comment.relationships.user` - это массив? Должно быть примерно так:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
  public function author()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id', 'user');
  }
}
```

На счет самого вопроса, есть несколько вариантов:

- парсить данные, перебирая ч/з `forEach`, тем самым подготовить массив для шаблона vue;
- воспользоваться [деструктурированием](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), плюс создавать вложенный компонент для пользователя куда ч/з атрибуты передавать свойства.

Расшифровка реляционных данных (relationships) должны быть в поле `included`:

```html
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON:API paints my bikeshed!",
       "user_id": "9"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/articles/1"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/author",
          "related": "http://example.com/articles/1/author"
        },
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
      },
      "comments": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/comments",
          "related": "http://example.com/articles/1/comments"
        },
        "data": [
          { "type": "comments", "id": "5" },
          { "type": "comments", "id": "12" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }],
  "included": [{
    "type": "people",
    "id": "9",
    "attributes": {
      "first-name": "Dan",
      "last-name": "Gebhardt",
      "twitter": "dgeb"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/people/9"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "comments",
    "id": "5",
    "attributes": {
      "body": "First!"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "2" }
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/comments/5"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "comments",
    "id": "12",
    "attributes": {
      "body": "I like XML better"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/comments/12"
    }
  }]
}
```

**UPD** Ссылки на [спецификацию](https://jsonapi.org/format/) и [реализации](https://jsonapi.org/implementations/)

**UPD** Пример реализации по просьбе ТС. В снипете НЕ работает. Использует `json` указанный в снипете выше.

```js
Vue.component('user-card', {
  template: `<div>
            <b>{{ fullName }}</b>
        </div>`,

  props: {
    attributes: Object,
  },

  computed: {
    fullName() {
      return `${this.attributes['first-name']} ${this.attributes['last-name']}`
    }
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      articles: [],
      comments: [],
      users: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getUser() {
      return (user_id) => {
        return this.users.find((item) => user_id == item.id)
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchResource()
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchResource() {
      const response = await fetch('articles.json')
      const json = await response.json()

      this.articles = json.data
      this.comments = json.included.filter(item => 'comments' === item.type)
      this.users = json.included.filter(item => 'people' === item.type)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="({ id, attributes: {title, user_id} }, index) in articles" :key="id">
    <div>{{ title }}</div>
    <user-card v-bind="getUser(user_id)"></user-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, как всегда) Делал api по репозиторию(из той статьи), не было там об этом. Буду разбираться

Comment: Вот на русском перевод той [статьи](https://medium.com/@bad4iz/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-api-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0-json-api-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-laravel-5-5-76f4da2f5ca8)